# MySQL Nested Sets adding node above selected node

Tags: mysql, sql, nested-sets

I have been trying to figure this out for a while, I have a MySQL query to add a node into the list, example:

> Heren
>
> -Pakken
>
> -Schoenen
>
> Dames

I'd like to add 'Children' before male. In this case, someone would say: Add Children before Male.

This is the query for adding Children after Male.

> LOCK TABLE `categories` WRITE;
>
> SELECT @myRight := `rght` FROM `categories` WHERE `name` = 'Male';
>
> UPDATE `categories` SET `rght` = `rght` + 2 WHERE `rght` > @myRight;
>   UPDATE `categories` SET `lft` = `lft` + 2 WHERE `lft` > @myRight;
>
> INSERT INTO `categories`(`name`, `lft`, `rght`) VALUES('Children',
>   @myRight + 1, @myRight + 2);
>
> UNLOCK TABLES;

So, from:  http://cl.ly/image/1U3O2k1F2I1T to: http://cl.ly/image/1D0k1Z1D2c18

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
LOCK TABLE `categories` WRITE;

SELECT @myLeft := `lft` FROM `categories`
WHERE `id` = '. $where .';

UPDATE `categories` SET `rght` = `rght` + 2 WHERE `rght` > @myLeft;
UPDATE `categories` SET `lft` = `lft` + 2 WHERE `lft` > @myLeft OR `lft` = @myLeft;

INSERT INTO `categories`(`name`, `lft`, `rght`) VALUES("'. $name .'", @myLeft, @myLeft + 1);

UNLOCK TABLES;
```